# Eventhub Trigger Setup Local Dev for VSCode

Tags: python, azure-functions, azure-eventhub

I've been banging my banging my head on this one all day but just can't get my local VSCode dev environment to handle EventHub triggering with the Python worker.

> Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Error indexing method 'Functions.myfunctionname'. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.EventHubs: Value cannot be null.
>   Parameter name: receiverConnectionString.
>
> Function 'Functions.myfunctionname' failed indexing and will be disabled.
>   [10/22/2018 1:17:40 AM] No job functions found. Try making your job classes and methods public. If you're using binding extensions (e.g. Azure Storage, ServiceBus, Timers, etc.) make sure you've called the registration method for the extension(s) in your startup code (e.g. builder.AddAzureStorage(), builder.AddServiceBus(), builder.AddTimers(), etc.)

The documentation is pretty lite when it comes to this stuff so I'm not sure if these event trigger just aren't supported or if I'm just not setting it up correctly.

This is a what my local.settings.json looks like:

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "python",
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "{AzureWebJobsStorage}",
    "EventHub":"Endpoint=sb://privatename.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=SharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=key here"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you run `func extensions install` from the command line and then try again?

For reference, here are some useful examples/pointers:

- https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-python-worker/tree/master/tests/eventhub_functions/eventhub_trigger
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-event-hubs

Comment: Yes that command runs and appears to install all the extensions correctly. I'm trying with within VSCODE and I think it's the local.settings.json file that isn't correct. But in all my Googling I didn't see that pure example from Elvis so let me go back and make sure my main .py file matches and give it another go. Thanks so much for the help with this! I'll report back if it works!

Comment: After fiddling with it a bit more I was able to get the function to start up correctly on my local box. Thanks for the help! I was wondering if you guys had any example of accessing the eventhub data via python as the function is trigger. I'd like to pull the massage body as a string and then send it to a http webhook trigger for further processing but I can't find a good example how to access the message body info.

Comment: You can use the `get_body()` method to obtain the contents of the message body as a string. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-functions/azure.functions.eventhubevent?view=azure-python

Comment: Thanks again! With that little bit of info I was able to get the function running and sending events to a http endpoint exactly as I wanted. Thanks so much for your help!